# Can't collect XMP while walking or standing

Tags: ingress

I can't collect XMP while walking. I am standing on top of it but can't collect it. Any solution to that?

Comment: You probably checked this yourself, but is your XM bar full?

Comment: I had this a few time too since the XM drought. The XM is in the action range and the XM bar is not full. Still no XM is collected, even after waiting for minutes standing still. Restarting the app helped me in these situations. (iOS)

Comment: No the xm bar is not full but still i can't collect xm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when your connection to the servers is slow/failing.

When Ingress knows you have no network connection (the red notification top-right) it will pretend to scoop up xm; when it thinks you have a working connection it will only scoop up xm on your screen once it has had confirmation back from the server that the xm has been collected and logged against your account.